# jquery variable and selector

Tags: jquery

I create a variable where I load an html document into it:
`result = data;`

How would I get the item elements from the result:
    `$(result+ " item");` -> which doesn't work.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
$("#result_html item"); -> but with result not #result_html
```

Comment: ill add the pont when i can..there is a timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand:

```
$(result).find('item');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you want to select elements from the loaded document. To do so, you can pass the variable containing the document into jQuery as a context:

```
var item = $("#result_html item", result);
```

You could also `find` the element:

```
var item = $(result).find("#result_html item");
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$("#" + result + "_html item");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
var resultDivId = 'result';
var $result = $('#'+resultDivId);
// find:
$('items', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load or retrieve data from anywhere id-ed with jQuery.

If the content is HTML code, you would use the .html:

```
$('#wherever').html('your html (<p></p><div></div>, etc, goes here and will show in "wherever"');
to retrieve it, variable = $('#wherever').html();
```

If the content is pure text, like a result of some kind of concatenation or math, you could use plain .text:

```
$('#wherever').text('This text goes into "wherever"'); or
$('#wherever').text(2+2+4+5);

to retrieve it, variable = $('#wherever').text(); or
variable = $('#wherever').text()+55;
```